# jQuery Validator plugin in a React JS component doesn't validate phone numbers

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-validate

I have a react component with a phone number input which I am trying to validate for phone numbers. However when I enter even characters the validator return TRUE.
Here is the code:

```
var ProfileStore = require('../../../stores/profile/profile-store.js');
(function(win) {
  "use strict";
var OwnerPhone = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Router.Navigation, PropyIntlMixin],
    phoneChanged: function() {
      var inputEl = this.refs.owner_phone.getDOMNode();
      var phone = inputEl.value;
      this.validatePhone();
      ProfileStore.updatePhone(phone);
    },

    validatePhone: function() {
      $('.owner_phone_input').validate({
        rules:{
          OwnerPhone: {
            phoneUS: true,
            required: true
          }
        },
      });
      $(".btn-block").click(function() {
          alert("Valid: " + $(".owner_phone_input").valid());
          return false;
      });
    },

     render: function() {
       return(
         <div className="form-group-input">
          <input name="OwnerPhone"
            ref="owner_phone"
            className="form-control input-lg owner_phone_input"
            type="text"
             placeholder={this.getIntlMessage('manage-profile-content.type-in-phone-number')}
            value={this.props.phone}/>
            <div className="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" onClick={this.phoneChanged}>UPDATE PHONE</div>
         </div>
       );
     }
  });

  module.exports = OwnerPhone;
  })(window);
```

I guess I doing something wrong with the jQuery html tag selectors. There is no submit button or form tag but the function is triggered as expected when the button is hit.

Answer (score 0):

> "There is no submit button or form tag..."

While it's possible to create a handler function that triggers validation without a `submit` button, you **absolutely cannot** do any validation outside of a `<form></form>` container.  That's just how the jQuery Validate plugin was designed.  There is no workaround.

> "... but the function is triggered as expected when the button is hit."

Which function?  The `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin on your `<form>`.  If you are not using the proper HTML structure, then the plugin will do nothing.

---

The `phoneUS` rule requires inclusion of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js).